# How do I make these buttons responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTMl and a CSS instance.

I'm trying to make these buttons get smaller based on the screen size and to correlate into a column. Right now when I change the window size the buttons just disappear.

```css
/* grid */ 

.col-1of1 {
width: 100%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}

.col-1of2 {
width: 50%;
float: left;
}

.col-1of3 {
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
}

.col-1of4 {
width:25%;
float: left;    
}

.col-1of5 {
width: 20%;
float: left;
}

#p-button {
font-size: 1.5vmin;
color: white;
background: #F0AB00;
    position: relative;
width: 200px;
min-width:20px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 6px;
margin-top: 180px;
margin-right: 25px;
margin-left: 25px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s; /* Safari */
transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

#p-button: hover {
background: #970A82;
}
```

```html
<p id="player-text">Please select the number of players</p>

<div class="col-1of1" id="options">
<a href="form1.html?player=1&form=1"><p class="col-1of4" id="p-
button">1 Player</p></a> <!--button--> 
<a href="form1.html?player=2&form=1"><p class="col-1of4" id="p-
button">2 Players</p></a> 
<!--button--> 
<a href="form1.html?player=3&form=1"><p class="col-1of4" id="p-
button">3 Players</p></a> <!--button--> 
<a href="form1.html?player=4&form=1"><p class="col-1of4" id="p-
button">4 Players</p></a> <!--button--> 
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked into [@Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)?

Comment: @hodrobond this is what i have in the css 
    "@media (min-width: 500px) and (min-height: 375px) {
  .nav {
    display: block;
  }"

the code was given to me so i'm trying to figure it out from that

Comment: As people have said, you want to learn to do @media queries, but also, for responsive designs, you'll be better off learning [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) [layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) instead of working with _floats_.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Media Queries. For Example.

```
@media(max-width: 767px){
    #p-button{
        font-size: 1vmin;
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also a problem of the buttons not stacking on top of each other. Which i want to happen when the window gets smaller/.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you have all your `p` elements with the same `id` and the only reason you are using that `id` is for CSS styling. `id`s must be unique. `p-button` should be a class, not an `id`.

Next, you have your column class set to be responsive because you are using a percentage for the `width` (that's good), but then you are hard coding the `p` elements to a `width` of `200px`, which is overriding that percentage because you had the `p` elements using an `id` based selector (the most specific type of selector). Changing to classes and removing the static `200px` width allows the buttons to grow/shrink.

After that, using `min-width` **and** `max-width` is an essential part of responsive design because people may have tiny or huge viewports and you need to set reasonable limits.

Also, (while technically valid), it's better to put `a` elements inside of the `p` elements for better semantics.

Here's a cleaned up version. Run the code snippet and then click the "full page" link at the top, right of the window to expand it and you will see the buttons get bigger and go from a grid layout to a row layout. Then, click the "close" link at the very top, right of that window and you'll see the buttons shrink and change their layout again.

```css
/* grid */ 
.col-1of1 {
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.col-1of2 {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}

.col-1of3 {
 width: 33.33%;
 float: left;
}

.col-1of4 {
 width:25%;
 float: left; 
}

.col-1of5 {
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}

.p-button {
 font-size: 1.25vw;
 background: #F0AB00;
  position: relative;
  min-width:75px;
  max-width:125px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 2em 2em 0 2em;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
    
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.p-button a {
 color: white;
}

.p-button:hover {
 background: #970A82;
}
```

```html
<p id="player-text">Please select the number of players</p>

    <div class="col-1of1" id="options">
    
      <p class="col-1of4 p-button">
        <a href="form1.html?player=1&form=1">1 Player</a>
      </p>
      <p class="col-1of4 p-button">
        <a href="form1.html?player=2&form=1">2 Players</a> 
      </p>
      <p class="col-1of4 p-button">
        <a href="form1.html?player=3&form=1">3 Players</a>
      </p> 
      <p class="col-1of4 p-button">
        <a href="form1.html?player=4&form=1">4 Players</a>
      </p> 
      
    </div>
```

Comment: I did all the changes that you specify. However the buttons still don't stack or change.

I also have an @media (min-width: 500px) and (min-height: 375px) {
  .nav {
    display: block;
}

Comment: As you can see, the code works here. You must have other code that is interfering with this code or you may have other errors that is preventing this code from working.

Answer (score 1):

CSS media queries is a great feature to do it.
You can do it by media queries

For example:

```
@media(max-width: 767px){
  .col-1of2,.col-1of3,.col-1of4,.col-1of5 {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  #p-button{
    font-size: 1vmin;
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

NB: I noticed that you use the same ID much time.Remember ID is a unique identifier. if you need to give the same style more than one element you have to use Class.

Answer (score 0):

You have a paragraph inside the hyperlink and the hyperlinks do not have a float:left. Make the following changes:

```
.col-1of4 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
a {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all is that you have a lot of redundant code. I made it work with only one `id="options"` All you needed was reffering to the width of buttons in `%`. I also included a cool [`calc()`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp) function which allows using both percentages and pixels when reffering to size of an element

```css
#options {
  width: 100%;
}
#options a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  background: #F0AB00;
  position: relative;
  width: calc( 25% - 30px );
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.5vmin;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<p id="player-text">Please select the number of players</p>

<div class="col-1of1" id="options">
  <a href="#"> 1 Player </a> <!--button--> 
  <a href="#"> 2 Players </a> <!--button--> 
  <a href="#"> 3 Players </a> <!--button--> 
  <a href="#"> 4 Players </a> <!--button--> 
</div>
```